# Time range query caching

Tags: algorithm, caching, range-query

I have a problem where I am searching for time t1 to time t2 and putting that in cache , if I have to search for t1 to t3 where t3 > t2
then I can take t1 to t2 from cache and search from t2 to t3

I have used Segment Tree for this ,but now the problem is it has fixed root value and i am doing real time search how can I append segment tree dynamically

I also don't know if its possible,can  someone help me with some example or any place where such thing is implemented

Comment: http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/19080